# keep getting error 1009 with gotoAndPlay as3

Tags: actionscript-3, typeerror

i'm getting error 1009 all the time. This is the code and output
code:

```
stop();
MovieClip(parent).gotoAndPlay(3);
```

Output:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   XPlayFla_fla::Symbol43_41/frame86()[XPlayFla_fla.Symbol43_41::frame86:2]

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Where did you define `parent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your MovieClip(parent) is null.

Try this and let me know the output

```
var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(parent);
if( mc == null )
    trace( "parent is not a movie clip" );
else
    mc.gotoAndPlay(3);
```